# Shiro based Authentication for rest api in a bundle not working

Tags: java, rest, shiro

I am using shiro for authenticating my rest api, I have configured the jaxrs to use the ShiroFeature like

```
<jaxrs:server address="/" id="shiroRestService">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="shiroRestServiceImpl"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="org.apache.shiro.web.jaxrs.ShiroFeature"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>
```

and in my rest service I have use the @RequiresAuthentication like

```
@Path("shiro")
@RequiresAuthentication
public interface ShiroRestService {
    @GET
    @Path("hello/{name}")
    public String handleGet(@PathParam("name") String name);
}
```

my shiro.ini file is

```
exampleuser = examplepassword, examplerole

[roles]
examplerole = something:readpermission

[urls]
/** = noSessionCreation, authcBasic
```

But my rest api can be accessed without authentication, I have checked all the solutions mentioned here and the tutorials in other blogs but all of them talk about authenticating a rest api inside a web application(war file) mine is a jar file without web.xml. Please let me know how to resolve the issue

The complete code can be found in [github](https://github.com/vineethvnair0/Karaf/tree/master/shiro-rest-auth)

Comment: How are you initializing Shiro in your environment?  I'm not sure how Karaf handles servlet listeners and the like.

Comment: @BrianDemers am not sure how to do that in an OSGI environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented basic authentication with shiro for jax-rs and the source is available at https://github.com/nmojir/rest-basic-auth. 
Additionally I realized that RequiresAuthentication annotation does not work on an interface and it worked on a concrete class for me. But I didn't realised why!